# Can't find logs using appengine/log

Tags: google-app-engine, go, cron

I have this code:

```
// main.go
package magnum

import (
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/tasks/backup", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    log.Debugf(ctx, "Testing cron tasks using Go")
}
```

---

```
// cron.yaml
cron:
- description: extraction
  url: /tasks/backup
  schedule: every 5 minutes
```

And I'm not seeing "Testing cron tasks using Go" text when I check the logs on GAE dashboard. Facts:

- Locally, I can see that text when I test the cron task using development environment
- On deployed, I can see a successful request on GAE dashboard when task is performed
- Standar Environment

What could I be missing?

Comment: Are you testing locally or deployed to App Engine?

Comment: Both. Locally I can see logs. On deployed I can't

Comment: Standard environment or Flexible environment?

Comment: @BrettJ. Standard. Just added those details to the questions

Answer (score 0):

I believe the local development server doesn't by default display logged messages, try starting your local development server with this [additional argument](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/local-devserver-command):

```
dev_appserver.py --log_level=info
```

You can also pass the `--logs_path=...` argument if you want to log the output to a file in addition to the console. Depending on the amount of logging you need to do that might be useful as well.

For your deployed application, you can find your logged application messages in the [Logging section of the Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer). If you don't see them ensure that the drop-down filter has **GAE Application** selected.

Comment: For local server I can see them through shell output. For the deployed version I checked the log viewer, selected the GAE Application and "All logs" filter, but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since the first post, but recently I had the same problem with go 1.11 GAE Standard, and had to switch to use cloud.google.com/go/logging package.